# What is the screenshot tag for?

Tags: discussion, tags

I asked a question about [how to take a screenshot in Hearthstone](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/136509/559). I tagged that question with [screenshot](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screenshot), but [kalina](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/52800/kalina) made a [revision removing it](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/136509/revisions). Given kalina's rep I am going to defer to her judgement, but it did raise some questions in my mind about the tag:

- When asking about how to take a screenshot why is the screenshot tag not applicable?
- If the tag is not to be used for this type of question when should it be used?
- Is it simply because the tag is pseudo ambiguous?

Comment: Note that there aren't any *other* questions using the tag...

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Good point, but I didn't look when I tagged the question as it auto completed so I assumed there were others.

Comment: There were.  They were removed.

Comment: @fbueckert that sounds so ominous. :-)

Comment: Nah, not ominous.  Just kalina going on a massive cleaning spree.  We had ~17 questions with the tag this morning.  Now, none at all.  And all was right with the world once again.

Comment: Just a nitpick, Don't always choose rep when deciding whose judgement to defer to. If you're ever unsure of someone's motives, check meta, and if you can't find anything, ask them. They'll (usually) be happy enough to explain :)

Comment: Screenshot is a meta tag, we don't like meta tags because they don't add anything to the question/content that doesn't already exist in the question/content, it's not useful for sorting questions and nobody specialises or is going to have an innate interest in screenshotting. It shouldn't have existed. I set fire to it, now it no longer exists. It certainly was nothing personal.

Comment: @kalina I definitely did not take it personally. The ability to edit people's questions is one of my favorite features of Stack Exchange. Just curios if you guys had deemed the tag as meta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If the tag is not to be used for this type of question when should it be used?

**Never.**

If you have a question about taking a screenshot, tag it with the game you're trying to take a screenshot in.

Comment: The current tag wiki/excerpt makes it sound like it's OK to use for these purposes. Suggesting normalisation of data.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie not anymore

Comment: @kalina Excellent.